# Eigenvalue of symmetric matrix with same diagonal elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}  10 & 6 \\ 6 & 10 \end{bmatrix} $$
I have used the following method
$$ \begin{vmatrix}  (10- \lambda) & 6 \\ 6 & (10-\lambda) \end{vmatrix} = 0 $$
Solving this I'm getting
$$ (10 - \lambda)^2 = 36 $$
which gives me $\lambda = 4$. But that's the only eigenvalue I'm getting from this, how to calculate the other eigenvalue?

Comment: $10-\lambda=\pm6$

Comment: Its 16... Calculate the other zero of that polynomial...

Comment: Obviously, $\lambda = 16$ is also a root of the polynomial.

Comment: For $2\times2$ matrix $M$, eigenvalues are two numbers like $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that $$\lambda_1+\lambda_1=tra(M)=20$$ and $$\lambda_1\times \lambda_2=det(M)=64$$. Now what are these two numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Motivated from the comments of @tired
Your matrix
$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}  10 & 6 \\ 6 & 10 \end{bmatrix} $$
Calculating eigen values:
$$ \begin{vmatrix}  (10- \lambda) & 6 \\ 6 & (10-\lambda) \end{vmatrix} = 0 $$

The eigenvalues on solving this,

$$ (10 - \lambda)^2 = 36 $$
$ 100+\lambda^2-20 \lambda = 36 $
$ \lambda^2-20 \lambda + 64= 0 $
$\lambda = 16,4 $